# amChart chartScrollbar does not work on mobile devices

Tags: charts, amcharts

I have web app which runs on mobile devices and uses amChart. The chart itself is working fine but the chartScrollbar doesn't react on touch events. Both sliders can't be move so it's not possible to zoom into the chart.

This is my code:

```
            var chartData = this._getData();

            var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.categoryField = "date";
            chart.dataProvider = chartData;
            chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
            chart.pathToImages = qx.util.ResourceManager.getInstance().toUri("resource/app/external libraries/");
            chart.valueAxes.title = "Nm³";
            chart.addTitle("Configured Chart 1",14,"#000000",false);

            var graphLine = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graphLine.valueField = "value";
            graphLine.type = "line";
            graphLine.title = "Ausstoß Biogas";
            graphLine.bullet = "round";
            graphLine.bulletBorderAlpha =  1;
            graphLine.bulletColor =  "#FFFFFF";
            graphLine.bulletSize = 5;
            graphLine.hideBulletsCount = 50;
            graphLine.lineThickness = 2;
            graphLine.useLineColorForBulletBorder = true;

            chart.addGraph(graphLine);

            var categoryAxis = new AmCharts.CategoryAxis();
            categoryAxis.parseDates = true;
            categoryAxis.dashLength = 1;
            categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;

            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.title ="Nm³";
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
            chartScrollbar.autoGridCount = true;
            chartScrollbar.graph = graphLine;
            chartScrollbar.scrollbarHeight = 40;
            chart.chartScrollbar = chartScrollbar;

            var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
            legend.useGraphSettings = true;
            legend.align = "center";
            chart.addLegend(legend);

            chart.categoryAxis = categoryAxis;

            chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);

            this.addListenerOnce("appear", function() {
                chart.write(this.getChildControl("comp").getContentElement().getDomElement());
                this.addListener("resize", function(){
                    chart.invalidateSize()
                });
            }, this);
```

Is there a way to fix this? Or is there a different way to use the amChart zooming functionality on mobile devices?

Comment: Do you use the latest version? Try setting chart.panEventsEnabled = true;

Comment: Yes I just upgraded to the latest version but the behavior is still the same: on mobile I can't drag the sliders. I also set chart.panEventsEnabled = true; but it had no effect...

Comment: Can you drag the scrollbar of a stock chart on home page of amcharts.com?

Comment: I tryed to drag the sliders of the "Drawing Trend Lines" Stock Chart(http://www.amcharts.com/demos/drawing-trend-lines/Date) on a Nexus 7 tablet but the scrollbar doesn't seem to react to tap or drag events. Aswell I tried the "Based Data"-Chart (http://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-data/#theme-none) which is basicly the same as I'm using in my application but same result...

Comment: I tested these samples with like 6 different touch devices and all worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I've added a listerner for the zoomToIndexes() function :

```
chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

function zoomChart() {
chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 40, chartData.length - 1);
}
```

Now that the chart is pre-zoom to certain indexes I'm able to drag the slides, not sure why. It's a bit sluggish but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chart.tapToActivate = false` property for chart to work properly with mobile devices.